# background image fadein fade out with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

hello
is it possible to fade in / fade out a couple of images in the css background image of the BODY itself?  (i know it's possible in a div)
regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The `background-image` property doesn't have its own separate opacity setting. It's `opacity` can only be affected only by the `opacity` setting of the element itself.

You'll need to use a container element if you don't want to fade the rest of the `<body>` content.